# HighCharts Polar Chart shows me Line/Bar graph instead, I have already try every example in stackoverflow/forum

Tags: charts, highcharts, react-highcharts

----SOLVED----

If you have the same problem try to add a conditional, the error is because HighcartsMore is trying to run and it is an empty object when initialise.

`import Highcharts from 'highcharts';

import HighchartsReact from 'highcharts-react-official';

import HighchartsMore from 'highcharts/highcharts-more';

if (typeof Highcharts === "object") {

```
HighchartsMore(Highcharts)
```

### }`

I am working with HighCharts, React, NextJs and Typescript.
I am showing multiple graphs with Highcharts and it is working perfectly well but now I am trying to implement the Polar Chart and it is not showing as a Polar chart, I see it as line/bar/column chart.

This is what I want:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JtiWT.png)
This is what I have:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HE1fV.png)

I read everywhere about the following solutions:

- Polar true instead type" polar (for me it is the same still showing columns)
   `chart: { polar: true, },`
- Install HighchartsMore from 'highcharts/highcharts-more'; (in npm deprecated) I also installed this and it shows me an error:

`import Highcharts from 'highcharts';
import HighchartsReact from 'highcharts-react-official';
import HighchartsMore from 'highcharts/highcharts-more';

// Initialize the HighchartsMore module
HighchartsMore(Highcharts);`

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ONITg.png)

So, I need help to find what I should do.

Here is my code:

`import Highcharts from 'highcharts';
import HighchartsReact from 'highcharts-react-official';
import sdgPolarChart from "@/components/Charts/sdgPolarChart";

const SdgOverview: NextPageWithLayout = () => {

```
return(
    
    <div>
        <Head>
            <title>SDG Overview</title>
        </Head>
        <br></br>
        <div className={styles.dashboard_container_SDG}>
            <div className={`${styles.dashboard_title} ${styles.title_1_SDG}`}>
                <p>SDG</p>
            </div>
            <div className={styles.section_1}>
               
                <div className={styles.dashboard_chart_1}>
                    <HighchartsReact highcharts={Highcharts} options={sdgPolarChart} />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        
    </div>
)
```

}

export default SdgOverview`

---

`const sdgPolarChart = {

```
chart: {
    polar: true,
    type: 'line'
},

title: {
    text: 'Highcharts Polar Chart'
},

subtitle: {
    text: 'Also known as Radar Chart'
},

pane: {
    startAngle: 0,
    endAngle: 360
},

xAxis: {
    tickInterval: 45,
    min: 0,
    max: 360,
    labels: {
        format: '{value}°'
    }
},

yAxis: {
    min: 0
},

plotOptions: {
    series: {
        pointStart: 0,
        pointInterval: 45
    },
    column: {
        pointPadding: 0,
        groupPadding: 0
    }
},

series: [{
    type: 'column',
    name: 'Column',
    data: [8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1],
    pointPlacement: 'between'
}, {
    type: 'line',
    name: 'Line',
    data: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
}, {
    type: 'area',
    name: 'Area',
    data: [1, 8, 2, 7, 3, 6, 4, 5]
}]
```

}

export default sdgPolarChart`

Comment: Hi @Eliana Dominguez, Which Highcharts version do you use? Your chart options look fine, so the key should be the proper `highcharts-more` initialization. I've prepared  a live example: https://codesandbox.io/s/highcharts-react-demo-mtzrf3?file=/demo.jsx